# How to count entries by category?

Tags: date, google-sheets, group-by, count, categories

I'm having a hard time counting MALE and FEMALE counts per day.

```
Timestamp                    Sex
3/24/2021 23:00:14          Male
3/25/2021 23:33:41          Male
3/25/2021 23:58:09          Female
3/26/2021 0:22:37           Male
3/26/2021 1:03:51           Female
3/26/2021 2:07:57           Male
```

What I need to have:

```
Day         # of responses     # of male    # of female
24               1                1            0
25               2                1            1
26               3                2            1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using pivot table functionality you should be able to do it.

First, you should split your data into columns to look like this:
[image]

Select the table -> Data-> Pivot table -> Create

When you put the right columns in places, the result will look like this:
[image]

Put columns in these places:
[image]

Comment: What a relief! Now, it's time to deal the duplicate entries.